# Finding the lexicographically smallest palindrome

Tags: java, palindrome

I wrote the following code and outputs also come as required. However when I submit my code in a website, it always ends up showing that the answer is wrong.
Can anyone find any possible mistakes which are responsible for the errors(which I can't see any).

The task is to convert a given string into a palindrome(IF POSSIBLE). The input format is

```
a.bc    
.aacc
```

The outputs for the above are -1, two times as the strings can't be converted to palindrome, no matter what you keep in the place of `.`

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*; 
 class m
{
static int p,o,k,m;
public static void main(String args[])
{
  String a[] = new String[500];
  int e[] = new int[500];
int i,j;
 m o = new m();
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

int n = s.nextInt();

for(i=0;i!=n;i++)
{
    a[i] = s.next();

}

//FOR CHECKING NUMBER OF PAIRS
for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
    p=0;
    for(j = 0 ; j < a[i].length() ; j++)
    {
    if(a[i].charAt(j) == a[i].charAt(a[i].length() - 1 - j))
        {
            ++p;
        }
    }
    e[i] = p;
}


//IF STRING LENGTH IS EVEN

    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
 {
  for(j = 0 ; j < a[i].length() ; j++)
    {

      if(a[i].length()%2 == 0)
      {
         if(e[i] == (a[i].length() - 2))
         {
 String h = a[i].replace('.',a[i].charAt(a[i].length() - 1 - a[i].indexOf('.')));
             System.out.println(h);
             break;
         }               
         else
         {
             System.out.println("-1");
             break;
         }
      }
 //IF STRING LENGTH IS ODD        
      else
      {
          if(a[i].indexOf('.') == (((a[i].length() + 1 ) / 2 ) - 1))
          {
              if(e[i] == (a[i].length() ))
              {   
                  String g = a[i].replace('.','a');
                  System.out.println(g);
                  break;
              }

              else
              {
                  System.out.println("-1");
                  break;
              }
          }

        else if(e[i] == (a[i].length() - 2))                
        {
            String q = a[i].replace('.',a[i].charAt(a[i].length() - a[i].indexOf('.') - 1));
            System.out.println(q);  
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("-1");
            break;
        }
      }
    }             
    }
```

And the updated one:

```
 import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class m
{
    public static void main(String args[])
  {
      int i,j;
    Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
    char b[][] = new char [50][50];
    String a[] = new String [12345];
    int n = r.nextInt();

    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        a[i] = r.next(); 
        if(a[i] == " ")
            a[i] = null;
    }       

    //FOR INITIALISING THE ARRAY
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for( j = 0 ; j < a[i].length() ; j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = a[i].charAt(j);
        }
    }

  int ll;
  int pp = 0;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      int lena = a[i].length();
      pp = lena;
      ll = 0;
      for(j=0;j<(lena/2);j++)
      {
          if(b[i][j] == b[i][lena-1-j])
              ++ll;
           //System.out.println("ITS WORKING" +pp);
      }
      if(ll == pp/2)
  {
      System.out.println("-1");
     // System.exit(0);
      break;
  }
  }
  // System.out.println("ITS WORKING" +count);

  //FOR PRINTING THE array
 /* for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
  {
      for(j= 0 ; b[i][j]!='\0' ; j++)
      {
          System.out.println(b[i][j]);
      }
  }*/

  for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
    int len = a[i].length();
    for( j = 0 ; j < len/2 ; j++)
        {
            if(len%2 == 0)
            {
                if(b[i][j] == '.' && b[i][len-1-j] == '.')
                    b[i][j] = b[i][len-1-j] = 'a';

                else if(b[i][j] == '.' &&  b[i][len-1-j]!='.' ) 
                    b[i][j] = b[i][len-1-j];

                else if (b[i][j]!= '.' &&  b[i][len-1-j] == '.')
                    b[i][len-1-j] = b[i][j];

                else{
                    if(b[i][j] == b[i][len-1-j])
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("-1");
                        //System.exit(0);
                    //  hh = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    }
            }

            else if(len%2!=0)
            {
                if(b[i][(len-1)/2] == '.')
                    b[i][(len-1)/2] = 'a';
                else
            {

                if(b[i][j] == '.' && b[i][len-1-j] == '.')
                {
                    b[i][j] = b[i][len-1-j] = 'a';
                    //System.out.println("ITS WORKING");
                }

                else if(b[i][j] == '.' &&  b[i][len-1-j]!='.' )
                    b[i][j] = b[i][len-1-j];

                else if (b[i][j]!= '.' &&  b[i][len-1-j] == '.')
                    b[i][len-1-j] = b[i][j];

                else{
                    if(b[i][j] == b[i][len-1-j])
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("-1");
                        //System.exit(0);
                    //  hh = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    }
            }
            }


        }
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
  {
      for(j= 0 ; b[i][j]!='\0' ; j++)
      {
          System.out.print(b[i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println();
  }

}
}
```

Comment: Provide: 1. The problem statement. 2. A failing test case. 3. The expected output for that test case.

Comment: Well, the input should be a string with one '.'. The task is to retrive the smallest lexicographically smallest palindrome.A failing test case should have an output "-1". Lets just say a.c , which will never be a palindrome.

Comment: Impossible to say if the code is right or wrong, since there is no description *in the question text* describing in detail what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: @Andreas Hope this helps now. Kindly help me sort out the problem

Comment: [Palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) of `.aacc` is `ac.ca` or `ca.ac`, so what are you talking about? The lexicographically smallest palindrome of the two would then be `ac.ca`.

Comment: @Andreas .aacc is a string i gotta check if this can be made a palindrome by substituting a letter from 'a'-'z' in the place of '.'   since there is no possible way(in the case of ".aacc") of converting the given string to a palindrome, the output should be -1.

Comment: @Andreas lets just take .aacc for instance, what would be the letter to be substituted in the place of '.' to make .aacc a palindrome? none right.

Comment: So as you can obviously see, your problem statement is very badly formulated. So let me quote the description of a reason to close your question: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Andreas I guess I should have! But this is my first question and would surely like to thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: In what sense do you “submit (your) code in a website”?

Comment: @Ole V.V. Like i had to submit my code in a contest

Comment: When I run your code, it seems to work as expected on input containing exactly 1 dot. With no dots (e.g., `abba`) or more than one dot (`ab..`) it seems to print -1 always. I cannot tell whether this is as expected (as your web site expects it!).

Comment: Does your web site give any other message except your program is incorrect? It would be really nice to know more.

Comment: @OleV.V. Sadly, it doesnt. It just shows that answer is wrong

Comment: @OleV.V. You got it right! I guess that's the mistake. My code isn't supporting the no dot and dots more than 1 cases. I guess thats the problem

Comment: That’s great — I hope you’re correct. I posted the same as in answer in case you want to mark it as correct after you’ve verified whether it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code, it seems to work as expected on input containing exactly 1 dot. With no dots (e.g., `abba`) or more than one dot (`ab..`) it seems to print -1 always. I cannot tell whether this is as expected (as your web site expects it!). It’s my best guess at what could be wrong.

To handle more than one dot, if it were me I would:

1. Convert the String to something that can be modified, like a StringBuffer, StringBuilder or char array.
2. Loop through the first half of the word only, always looking at the current char and the char at the same position counting from the other end (you already have the formula: `a[i].length() - 1 - j`). If both are dots, fill in 'a' in both places; if one is a dot, copy the letter from the opposite position; if none is a dot, they have to be the same, or you can print -1 and break out of the loop (or maybe better, set a boolean variable to indicate failure to construct a palindrome).
3. If there is a dot in the middle position (only possible with odd length), replace it with 'a'.
4. If successful so far, print the modified word. Except for the no dots case: if the word is still the same as the input, also print -1 instead.

If you require further help. I believe we need a more precise problem statement, more precise requirements for your program.

Comment: The no dot case should have output -1(This is correct, which means that the given string can no more be converted to a palindrome). the error is that its not checking for more than 1 dot case. Really appreciate your concern. Thanks

Comment: any idea on how i can approach onto the muliple dots case, because i found it too complex to code.

Comment: See edit; I have filled in something like a pseudo-algorithm.

Comment: Step 3b seems wrong. Any mismatched characters would have caused code to return -1 in step 2, so if you get to step 3, the buffer will contain a palindrome, even if no `.` was found, so step 3 should never return -1. Your own example of `abba` illustrates this scenario.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for the review. :-) It depends on the requirements. The OP wrote in a comment “The no dot case should have output -1(This is correct, which means that the given string can no more be converted to a palindrome).” I too would have preferred to count `abba` as convertible to palindrome.

Comment: @Olive V.V. can you please check this one too... I'm not sure where its going wrong. I'm sorry if I'm embarrasing you!

Comment: Don’t expect too much. :-) I entered a number of strings, and most of them gave the expected output, with 0, 1, 2 and 3 dots. Only `b..c.` was funny; I expected `bcacb`, but the program first printed `-1`, then `bcac.`.

Comment: My suspicion goes here: after `else if (len % 2 != 0) {` (the odd length case) you have an if-else statement. I don’t think that `else` is correct; I think it should be executed no matter if the if condition was true or false. Am I right?

Comment: @Ole V.V. yeah you are.

Comment: I want to have these  things 1.to print the string there itself when everything goes right and 2. I'm getting this non zero exit code when I'm executing in website